# JS How to compare and count the same elements in each first multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this JS code:

```
    $.get('file.log', function(data) {
      var lines = data.split("\n");
      $.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
        var url = elem.match(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig);
        var parts = url.toString().split(',h');             
        var file=parts[0];
        var hostname='h' + parts[1];
    });
```

By parts[0] I get each hostname how to compare them between each other and show the most repeatable? As I understand it's first elements of the multidimensional array.

Here is the example of log file:

```
    85.164.152.30 - - [23/May/2012:14:01:05 +0200] "GET http://www.vgtv.no/video/img/94949_160px.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3889 "http://www.vgtv.no/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use another object to collect statistics.

```
var hostnameFrequencies = {};

$.get('file.log', function (data) {
    var lines = data.split("\n");
    $.each(lines, function (n, elem) {
        var url = elem.match(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig);
        var parts = url.toString().split(',h');
        var file = parts[0];
        var hostname = 'h' + parts[1];
        hostnameFrequencies[hostname] = hostnameFrequencies[hostname] ? hostnameFrequencies[hostname] + 1 : 1;
    });
    console.log(hostnameFrequencies);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I have this in console log: Object { http://www.vgtv.no/=63, http://touch.vg.no/=68, http://www.vg.no/=1000, more...} But how now to display only five the most repeatable?